# DroneKit for DJI drone

Tags: python, dji-sdk, dronekit-python, dronekit

I am learning to control drone using different SDKs or development kits and came across the [dronekit](http://python.dronekit.io/). What droneKit do is:

> DroneKit-Python 2.x helps you create powerful apps for UAVs. These
>   apps run on a UAV’s **Companion Computer**, and augment the autopilot by
>   performing tasks that are both computationally intensive and require a
>   low-latency link (e.g. computer vision).

As i can run the dronekit on companion computer like (Rasberry Pi or any else single board PC) that can talk with the flight controller but remember

> DroneKit-Python is compatible with vehicles that communicate using the
>   **MAVLink** protocol (including most vehicles made by 3DR and other
>   members of the DroneCode foundation). It runs on Linux, Mac OS X, or
>   Windows.

Keeping in mind that I can only work with Mavlink protocol supported flight controllers, if i want to use droneKit.

But What i want to do is to control or run DK on DJI drones. Is there any workaround available to use DK on DJI drones?

Answer (score 0):

There is no access to the underlying communications protocols for DJI drones.  You must use their SDK.

Comment: how their sdk communcate with the flight controller(A3/n3) or onboard sensors? where should sdk will run? Can i add my own flight controller to DJI drone like in this case pixhawk

Answer (score 0):

To control the DJI products, please use DJI SDKs. DJI has provided abundant documentation and sample code for you to learn how to use the SDKs, please check below:

We have abundant documentation and sample code for you to learn how to use our SDKs, please check below:

- MSDK: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/index.html
- UXSDK: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/ux_sdk_introduction.html
- OSDK: https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/introduction/homepage.html
- PSDK: https://developer.dji.com/payload-sdk/documentation/introduction/index.html

Github Samples: https://github.com/dji-sdk